# Return JSON with errorhandler in Python Cloud Function

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Python for a HTTP Cloud Function and want to set the default error handler to return JSON instead of HTML.

```
from flask_expects_json import expects_json
import payment_orders_schema
from flask import jsonify, Flask

schema = payment_orders_schema.schema

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_request(error):
    return jsonify({'error': error.description}), 400


@expects_json(schema)
def add_payment_order(request, methods=['POST']):

    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)

    if request_json:
        return jsonify(request_json), 200
```

First, I'm not sure if I can define the `app` variable in a Cloud Function and second, the `@app.errorhandler` is not working, the Cloud Functions returns HTML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, I'm not sure if I can define the `app` variable in a Cloud Function

You can't. Although Cloud Functions uses Flask to serve requests under the hood, it doesn't support setting up your own Flask WSGI `app` as you're doing here.

You would, however, be able to deploy this as-is to the [App Engine Standard Python 3.7 Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/). You might want to consider doing this instead.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I expected!

Comment: Hey Dustin, I'm revisiting this and just wondering.. why does the nodejs runtime allow you to manipulate the [express app](https://gist.github.com/wesley-haigh/3cd13e0ce9b623ab6fd13684510a07a9#file-index-js) and define custom routes for example and the python runtime doesn't? I'm creating a restful API with GCF and am wondering the best way to handle a url like `resource/:id/resource2`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching a `400` error, which is a `BAD REQUEST` error, perhaps you could try catching a `404` error, which is a `NOT FOUND` error. I think this is what you really want to do since a `404` type error is what's received when a user tries to navigate to a page on your site which doesn't exist. Try changing your error handler to the following and see if that helps:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def error_404(error):
    return jsonify({'error': error.description}), 404
```

Hopefully that helps!